# Delaying startup applications

Tags: startup

Is there a way to delay applications on the startup? I have a Nimbus installed (Weather widget) and set-up to start on the startup, but it looks like Nimbus actually starts before my Wi-Fi is done connecting to the network. So I only get 0 temperature on my widget.

It isn't a big deal, but i would be nice to have accurate temperature after every boot. This problem can be solved by reopening application, but it isn't aesthetic enough. We all know that eOS is all about aesthetics.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd
nano autostart.sh
```

Put this into the file

```
#!/bin/bash
name_of_the_app & sleep 10s
```

Save with ctrl+o
Exit with ctrl+x

Make the file executable:

```
sudo chmod +x autostart.sh
```

Add autostart.sh to autostart.

Go to system settings -> Applications -> Startup tab

Click directory plus icon (bottom left corner)

Type in custom command instead of Search applications. See image. [image]

Type there:

/home/yourusername/autostart.sh

Delete the previously added nimbus app from the autostart and leave only autostart.sh script for this nimbus app.